# how to echo default date 0000-00-00 using date("F j, Y, "); if the date isn't updated?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, strtotime

in my database default value of date is set to `not null 0000-00-00`and i use the date format `date("F j, Y, ");` to print out the date.

if i echo the date using `strtotime` function in the following way,

```
echo date("F j, Y", strtotime($row_schedule['meeting_date']));
```

it returns `November 30, -0001` based on the set default date `0000-00-00`

whereas if i update the default value of date from `0000-00-00` to a real time date like, `2013-02-28` it gives the appropriate output as it should be like,

`February 28, 2013`

my question is how can i print default date as `0000-00-00` but not `November 30, -0001` using my current output method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write your own function

```
function myDate($time){
  if($time == '0000-00-00')
     return $time;
  return date("F j, Y", strtotime($time));
}
```

and then just `echo myDate($row_schedule['meeting_date']);`.

Answer (score 1):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns false for invalid dates - this is where your integrity check should be.

```
$time = strtotime($var_from_db);
if($time!==false)
  echo date("F j, Y", $time);
```

Comment: Nice, but I think my solution is better, because you don't need to call a `strtotime` function when it is not necessary, what do you think?

Comment: @Voitcus I think weak-type languages have their pros and cons... the overheads of native functionality like `strtotime` seem negligible to be honest.  For the sake of future-proofing code I think it's better to avoid direct string comparison where possible - my suggestion would cover *any* invalid date rather than one specific instance.  Inevitably preferences will dictate choices though ;)

Comment: That's some idea. However, your code requires also `else` statement to put `0000-00-00` as the Silent Pond asked, so if he would need to put it in many places, it would be better to use a function anyway.

Comment: @Voitcus Not necessarily - OP hasn't made it obvious that it should be printed to the screen and in any case isn't useful.  If you are a stickler for number of lines you can always use a ternary operator, for example: `echo ($time!==false) ? date("F j, Y", $time) : '0000-00-00';` - I put the if statement in the answer purely for readability :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition,

```
echo $row_schedule['meeting_date'] == '0000-00-00'?
'your default time/string':
date("F j, Y", strtotime($row_schedule['meeting_date']));
```

Answer (score 0):

the other simple method is

```
if ($row_schedule['meeting_date'] == '0000-00-00') {
echo '0000-00-00';
}else{
echo
date("F j, Y g:i A", strtotime($row_schedule['meeting_date']));
}
```

thanks,